# Javascript: How do i target selected elements in a slideshow when hovering over one element?

Tags: javascript, slideshow

Alright, so I'm working on my own javascript slideshow which consist of cards. Right now I'm adding/looping through the cards and adding an eventlistener (mouseover and mouseout) to check if the user hovered over chosen card.

Now to the problem. I need to be able to target all of the cards (part 1, see image) which comes before the chosen card of the user and also all of the cards (part 2, see image) which comes after. But I have to target them individually. Basically the cards in part 1 will get one kind of styling and the cards in part 2 will get another one. The chosen card will get its own styling.

[image: Image example]

This is what I have so far. If someone could point me in the right direction, that would be great, thanks. I don't want to use any libraries, strictly javascript.

```js
var cards = [];
cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    //Do something
    console.log('Mouseover: Do something');
  });

  cards[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    //Do something
    console.log('Mouseout: Do something');
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff2cc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="card">Card-1</li>
  <li class="card">Card-2</li>
  <li class="card">Card-3</li>
  <li class="card">Card-4</li>
  <li class="card">Card-5</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Part 1 should just be the styling applied to all cards from the get go or if you need new styling on all of them before the user selects a card, make a new CSS class and in the workflow, change each cards class to the new CSS class for pre-card choosing, then make another CSS class for chosen card, and one last CSS class for post-chosen non selected cards, when the user selects a card apply the selected card style class to it, and iterate all the cards and apply the post-card-chosen CSS class to all which do not have the class of the selected card CSS class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set class for group/part 1, current card and group/part 2 separately.

You can possibly also listen to bubbling phase of event instead of multiple listener registration.

Check.

```js
let ul = document.querySelectorAll('ul')[0];
ul.addEventListener('mouseover', function(e) {  
  
  if(e.target.className.indexOf("card") === -1) { return; }

  let currentFound = false;  
  document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(function(card) {
  
    if(card === e.target) { 
      card.classList.add("current-card");
      currentFound = true;
    }
    else
    if(currentFound) {
      card.classList.add("next-cards");
    } 
    else {
       card.classList.add("previous-cards");
    }});
});  


ul.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.card').forEach(
    function(card) {
      card.classList.remove("previous-cards");
      card.classList.remove("next-cards"); 
      card.classList.remove("current-card");});
  });
```

```css
.container {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff2cc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.previous-cards {
  background-color: crimson;
}

.next-cards {
  background-color: darkred;
}

.current-card {
  background-color: indianred;
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="card">Card-1</li>
  <li class="card">Card-2</li>
  <li class="card">Card-3</li>
  <li class="card">Card-4</li>
  <li class="card">Card-5</li>
</ul>
```

If you would like to preserve the colors until next hovering just remove the *mouseout* listener and put its logic to start of mouseover listener right after if block.

Comment: Ahh thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

You can select the particular card and apply class name using jquery.

```js
var cards = [];
cards = document.querySelectorAll('.card');
for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
  cards[i].addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    //Do something
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    console.log('Mouseover: Do something');
  });

  cards[i].addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    //Do something
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    console.log('Mouseout: Do something');
  });
}
```

```css
.container {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.card {
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: #fff2cc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
}

.selected{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
  <li class="card">Card-1</li>
  <li class="card">Card-2</li>
  <li class="card">Card-3</li>
  <li class="card">Card-4</li>
  <li class="card">Card-5</li>
</ul>
```

you can even use simple css which will be comman for all the card.

when card class is hovered this css will execute.

```
.card:hover{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this with CSS and it's sibling selector:

```css
.card {
    background-color: red;
}

.card:hover ~ .card {
    background-color: green;
}
```

If you need to use JavaScript, use `[...mouseEnterCard.parentElement.children].indexOf(mouseEnterCard)` to get the element index and then loop over the elements with a lower/higher index.